# What to do with boatload of screen-resolution related questions?

Tags: discussion, editing, duplicates

I was browsing Ask Ubuntu for a bit and I found that there are a lot of screen-resolution related questions who are badly asked/answered or not answered at all.

A lot of the questions are very specific while a lot of the answers are the same.

Some examples:

- [Low resolution for nvidia quadro 600 on ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244357/low-resolution-for-nvidia-quadro-600-on-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1)
- [Problem with display resolution using a NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94001/problem-with-display-resolution-using-a-nvidia-quadro-nvs-160m?rq=1)
- [How can I set the display resolution to 800x480?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135791/how-can-i-set-the-display-resolution-to-800x480?rq=1)
- [Changing the screen resolution to the true resolution option not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306810/changing-the-screen-resolution-to-the-true-resolution-option-not-available?rq=1)
- [Screen size and resolution conflict](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313396/screen-size-and-resolution-conflict?rq=1)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/343821/screen-resolution?rq=1
- [My screen resolution is not listed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351946/my-screen-resolution-is-not-listed?rq=1)

I propose making an enourmous screen-resolution-troubleshooting question with all the small answers/workarounds combined. A bit like the [black-screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) question.

I would not mind doing the task of searching askubuntu for duplicates and combining all the answers in one question, but I'm not sure how to start and if that is the best solution.

## My current plan is:

1. Make a "My screen resolution is wrong, what options do I have to fix it?" question and make it a community wiki
2. Go through all the screen resolution questions, and add all the answers to my question (as community wiki answers)
3. Flag the questions that are horrible to be removed, Flag the others as duplicates and edit the ones that could be better (like Braiam said).

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The majority of "wrong screen resolution" questions (and most other questions relating to video corruption, graphics problems, visual glitches) are actually bugs in kernel mode setting or some other GPU operations for (nouveau, radeon, etc.) that should be reported upstream.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm big fan of canonical questions, I'm not big fan of duplicating incomplete, badly asked question against another question. Those need to be closed (just going by the title my finger is kind of ichin).

Duplicates should have the same quality of non-duplicates and we should make sure that the question against what we are duplicating will help OP.

- For now, the questions that could not be given a definitive solution for lack of information, being badly crafted, lack of quality, should be downvoted, commented and closed accordingly.
- The ones that the **accepted answer** by OP is the same procedure, flagged as duplicated.

  Editing the title/body if necessary to facilitate their searching. Be aware that if the problem is towards something specific, the title should reflect the same, i. e.: if OP's problem is with a Nvidia card X model, you can't flag it as duplicate of another with an AMD card Y model, and the title can't be too general either, since each solution is for each specific card.